# lftp mv command fails with "Operation not supported: 501 Not Implemented (MOVE)"

Tags: ftp, centos, lftp

I'm trying to download all the files from a folder and then move them to another folder.

Here's my command:

```
lftp ftp://domain.com -u user,password-e "mirror -L --verbose --parallel=2 --use-pget-n=10 --newer-than=now-30minutes  /folder-source1/ /folder-target/; mv /folder-source1/* /forlder-source1/folder-source2; bye"
```

Download goes fine, but `mv` doesn't work, here's my error:

> mv: Operation not supported: 501 Not Implemented (MOVE)

I'm using lftp v4.4.8 on CentOS, should I upgrade to 4.7 or is it another problem?

Comment: Lftp log file may provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the FTP server. It's the server that does not support the move.

Upgrading `lftp` cannot help.

The FTP server needs to support `RNFR` and `RNTO` FTP commands for the `lftp` `mv` command to work.

Comment: Well this is a very sad day then... Thank you

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to use the "mirror" from one ftp folder to another ftp folder (instead of download locally)?

Comment: That's a very complex question to cover in a comment. And unrelated to this question really. Anyway, FTP to FTP transfers (called FXP) are generally not allowed.